# Unknown property calling a method on my visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

Hi guys im getting an error 'Unknown property 'CAP_ManageDepartment.countriesOptions'' when im trying to use a method from the controller

Here is my method:

```
   @RemoteAction global static List<String> getCountriesOptions(ccrz.cc_RemoteActionContext ctxpage) {     
    List<String> allCountriesList = new List<String>{' Afghanistan',' Albania',' Algeria'};        
    return allCountriesList;
}
```

and here is where im trying to get it:

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="req_list_description">
        <apex:selectList value="{!editCountry}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!countriesOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Error: Unknown property 'CAP_ManageDepartment.countriesOptions'

what should i do ??